why does the f1 score declines from 1.0 to 0.0?
In the evaluation of a multi-class YOLOv8 model, the F1 confidence curve, why the F1 got dropped by 1.0 to 0.0 also it starts with 1.0? Why does it have to happen when there is an increase in the confidence? F1 confidence curve , recall confidence curve .
Most of the 'ultralytics' evaluation seems as same as mine (curve drops).
